# Scala stream keeps intermediary objects in memory

Tags: scala, stream, stack-overflow, memoization

I am trying to write a Stream in Scala and I do not get why it keeps some intermediary objects in memory (and eventually get out of memory).

Here is a simplified version of my code :

```
val slols = {
  def genLols (curr:Vector[Int]) :Stream[Int] = 0 #:: genLols(curr map (_ + 1))
  genLols(List.fill(1000 * 1000)(0).toVector)
}
println(slols(1000))
```

This seems to keep in memory the intermediary `curr` and I do not see why.

Here is the same code written with an iterator (much better memory consumption):

```
val ilols = new Iterator [Int] {
  var curr = List.fill(1000 * 1000)(0).toVector
  def hasNext = true
  def next () :Int = { curr = curr map (_ + 1) ; 0 }
}
val silols = ilols.toStream
println(silols(1000))
```

EDIT : I am interested in keeping the `0`s in memory, my goal is to not keep the `curr`s because they are juste useful to take a step of computation (it may not be obvious in my simplified example). And the `0`s alone cannot make an out of memory error (they are not so heavy to store).

Answer (score 2):

When you assign stream to a variable you prevent it's head from being garbage collected.

In first case that means that all the references for `cur` Vectors for each iteration are memoized.

In second case the situation is better, as iterator stores only single instance of `cur` at a time. But still, all `Int` elements of the stream are memoized.

Try replacing `val slols` with `def slols` if you don't need memoization.

And by the way, your two examples are not equivalent in terms of logic (probably you're aware of it).

Check [this article](http://blog.dmitryleskov.com/programming/scala/stream-hygiene-i-avoiding-memory-leaks/) for details.

Comment: To be clear, it's the by-name parameter to `#::` that is capturing the value of `curr`, and not the stream itself. The stream only memoizes the generated values - a lot of 0s in this case.

Comment: See my EDIT, I want to keep the `0`s. I understand that there will be 'no memoization' if I use `def`, because it will be a different stream every time (and the last one should be GC at some moment) (so I think it does memoize, but for nobody because it cannot be accessed, so it seems really bad to use `def`). J Cracknell, can you tell me more about the by-name parameter ? I was thinking it should be computed and unreferenced, but it is not, I do not see why. There is an explicit keyword for by-name that is `=>`.